# How to get Magento extension to run javascript when item added to cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm developing a Magento extension and having trouble trying to get it to run javascript when an item is added to cart.

In config.xml I have an observer

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

In Observer.php

```
public function itemAddedToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){}
```

This is firing (I can test by echo-ing).  But how do I get it to inject a block of javascript (preferably into the footer)?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Used Chris' solution, but instead of registry I used the session to avoid potential multi-user issues:

In Observer.php

```
public function itemAddedToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){}
    $itemAddedToCart = 'true';
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setItemAddedToCart($itemAddedToCart);
```

In my custom block (script.phtml):

```
<?php if($itemAddedToCart) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(<?php echo '"' . $this->__($itemAddedToCart) . '"' ?>);
    </script>
    <?php 
        // Clear itemAddedToCart session variable:
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsItemAddedToCart(); 
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Looks like you don't understand how it works. This event is triggered on back-end side after the user pushes "Add to Cart" button and at this moment you can't run JS because JS is run on client side (in browser). You have already got  the right answer for your question

Comment: Ended up using Chris' solution, but used the session instead of registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this via XML in the layout XML file of your extension.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" name="INSERT_CUSTOM_NAME_HERE" template="path/to/your/phtml/file.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Make sure you delete your cache because XML updates are only applied after refreshing your cache.

If you are using the default Magento theme you don't need to call this template because it automatically calls all children `$this->getChildHtml('');`.
But if you are using a custom theme you should add this to your footer.phtml: `$this->getChildHtml('INSERT_CUSTOM_NAME_HERE');`.

Or if you'd like to have the javascript on the cart page you should replace `<catalog_product_view>` with `<checkout_cart_index>`.

Comment: Thanks, but that will load on every page right?  I need to just execute this javascript 1 time when an event is triggered (item is added to cart).

Comment: No, it will only load on the catalog_product_view page. It's up to you to decide when to run what. You could for instance set a registry value in your observer which can be read in your footer template file which then can decide if the JavaScript code should run or not.

Comment: Cool. That sounds like a good solution. Sorry I'm pretty new to this -- do you have any examples on how I can set a registry value from the observer?

Comment: Mage::register('label', 'value');

Comment: And to read it; Mage::registry('label'); That should do it.
(Please upvote my answer if you found it useful.)

Comment: @Chris it's bad practice to use register in such way. There should not be logic related to View inside model observer. Layout updates is more than enough for resolving such task

Comment: @Serjio - How would you trigger a layout update to happen only when an observer event fires?

Comment: @Serjio Could give me(us) an example for how you would accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks @Chris - used Session instead of registry to prevent potential multi-user issues.  Updated my question with the code.